# Automatically push gem to RubyGems.org from a Continuous Integration server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have a Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment scenario where I want my build script to push a ruby gem directly from a public Build Server (teamcity.codebetter.com) to RubyGems.org.

The problem is: How can I specify my credentials? 
On my local machine I have them under ~/.gem/credentials and everything works fine but how can I tell the build server to push my gem?

Thanks and best regards,
  Steffen Forkmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the API itself to push the gems. See the POST /api/v1/gems endpoint: http://rubygems.org/pages/api_docs

Answer (score 0):

I would guess if you manually pushed once from the continuous integration box as the user who runs the CI software it could push in the future.

Comment: Yes. That's true, but as I said it is a public CI server. Adding the public CI user as a gem owner to my gem means every other project could possibly "update" my gem.

Comment: You could look at setting up a callback URL on a separate server, then  have your build process access that URL on successful build.